# Why is ArcGIS Feature Service layer incomplete once added to QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, feature-service

I'm running QGIS3 and I'm trying to a add property cadastre layer from a publicly hosted ArcGIS Feature Service connection. The connection works ok, but when I add the cadastre layer, not all polygons are imported/showing? I've confirmed that the cadastre do exist by referencing a WMS version, so I'm not sure if it's timing out or if there's something else I should be aware of?

Comment: Have you contacted the hosting organization?

Comment: I have. They suggested increasing the timeout for network requests to 180,000 (default was 60,000), which I did, but there's no change in performance.

Comment: is the url public? [if yes can it be shared for testing?]

Comment: What canvas extent are we talking about? How many features? What happens when you zoom in on the missing areas?

Comment: same here - about 40.000 line features, the qgis-table view shows all of those records correctly but the map displays roughly 5 % of the features when symbolized graduated - no problem when using single symbol-  @Darren did you find any solution